# find recent date between two dates and compare that result with another date inside where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a condition where inside the SQL where clause, I have to check for

```
MAX( date1, date2 ) > date 3.
```

`MAX()` just takes one parameter, so how to implement this?

Many thanks

Comment: Note:  This question was mis-tagged originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access SQL it will be:

```
IIf([date1] > [date2], [date1], [date2]) > [date3]
```

Answer (score 0):

using nested case

```
SELECT  
  CASE WHEN Date1 > Date2 THEN 
    case when Date1 > Date3 
         then
         --you can do something 
         end

    ELSE 
       case when Date2 > Date3 
       then
       --you can do something 
       end
    END AS MostRecentDate
    FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `greatest()` . . . as I think another answer points out.

But really the simplest way is `or`:

```
WHERE date1 > date3 OR date2  > date3
```

It is a question of judgement which is simpler.  The above or:

```
WHERE greatest(date1, date2) > date3
```

I would caution that the two are not equivalent.  The first behaves as expected if any of the date column have `NULL` value.  The second will never return true if any of the dates are `NULL`.

Comment: I am using MS-Access, sorry I tagged MySQL, and what i want to do is

Comment: Max(date1 , date2 ) and the result is to be compared with date 3

Comment: @PrabhaJose . . . The `OR` should work in any database.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than a nested case would be an OR condition:

```
CASE WHEN (date1 > date3) OR (date2 > date3) THEN
    stuff
ELSE
    not stuff
END
```

Comment: I am using MS-Access, sorry I tagged MySQL, and what i want to do is – 
     Max(date1 , date2 ) and the result is to be compared with date 3